# multiple images in tableview

Tags: ios, uitableview, memory-management, uiimageview

I have a tableview which needs a image to be shown on each cell.

I have like 1000 rows and image in each cell is different.

so how to efficiently handle images without causing any memory lean as far as image usage is concerned

Comment: TableView itself does for you. You don't need to bother about that.

Comment: tableview takes care of reusability of cells using reuseidentifier but what about image ? lots of bandwidth would be gone right ! is there anything that can reduce bandwidth

Comment: What are you worried about...images taking space or high internet uses while downloading image or cell taking time to load images?

Comment: Yes use some caching of images, like use AFNetworking+UIButton or AFNetworking+UIImage category to download and cache images automatically for you.

Comment: Yes @RohitKumar said..if you are worried about image caching and if you are using AFNetworking you can use AFNetworking+UIImage category else use SDWebImage.

Comment: Can we implement caching easily without using AFNetworking ?

Comment: But...what happen if image changed from server and the same name image saved in cache..? @Rohit Kumar

Comment: You need the change the URL on server side. Eg: save the image name with the timestamp.